# What should I do in the case of an account merge if I don't have access to one of the emails?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I found this account (on which I am posting) and requested a merge via Stack Overflow support. I clicked the confirm ownership link from the email associated with the other account, but as it stands, I don't have access to the email associated with this account. I own this account and can login. (The accounts *aren't* yet merged.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you still have access the account settings, you can simply change its email to one you have access to as said by Adam Lear:

> Since you have access to the account, you could just change the email to something you do have access to and request a merge again?

To do so, just simply go to "Edit Profile and Settings" then to "My Logins" and then add the new email and/or remove the old email.

Answer (score -1):

Both email/password pairs work since two accounts are merged in one. You could continue using both or remove/add others via [my logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current).

If you don't have access to the email in your original account (which you use to request the merge) but can login, you could add another email/login pair with a valid email. If you've got Stack Exchange login already, you would have to add have to add not SE one (for example, Google or Facebook).

If you have also included the unaccessible email when requested the merge ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz4kZ.png)), you have to request the merge again.

Comment: Maybe I should've clarified in the OP, the accounts *aren't* yet merged.